# VB.NET LIKE comparison with # and *

Tags: vb.net, string

I have the following file name: d#cument.txt

I want to compare to see if it matches pattern: d#cument*

I do this like this:

```
return "d#cument.txt" Like "d#cument*"
```

This returns **false**. The ending asterix seems to be the problem. Because if I change file name to just "d#cument" and Like pattern to "d#cument" it returns **true**.

Any idea why and/or workaround?

Comment: Return "d#cument.txt".Contains("d#cument")

Comment: @Malcor - while that solution returns true it is no general solution. This was just an example where Like fails. In all other cases it returns what is expected. I want to be able to use asterix as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx) states that # has a meaning in a Like pattern so you need to "escape" it by putting it between brackets :

```
Return "d#cument.txt" Like "d[#]cument*"
```

Alternatively you can use String.StartsWith to do the same thing without worrying with special chars.
Note also that though Like is convenient for simple patterns ; for things more complex it could be better to switch to Regex instead.

Comment: Also see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te33kb6t.aspx and for comparison with regular expressions see https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms235204(v=vs.100).aspx